# Can not connect to one wifi, but to others can

Tags: wireless, router

I can not connect to my wifi network, but I tried to other wifis and it worked fine. The network should be ok as I tried with other laptop and worked like a charm. In the past I could connect to it from my ubuntu as well, it stopped working just some days ago.
Router restart did not help. Is it possible that there is a problem with the wifi card? If yes, then why I can connect to other wifis. How to check in ubuntu what might be the problem.
Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you connect other devices to your router?

Comment: yes, only my ubuntu laptop has this problem

Comment: What is the encryption in you router? And what happens when you try to connect?

Comment: `sudo grep wlan0 /var/log/*` will show you some interesting data (if your wireless device is `wlan0`, otherwise substitute your device).